# How do I change the style of database data permanently using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, database, styles

I have a table that displays data from my database. On each row, there is a button that i made with jquery to cross the row out when clicked. When I refresh the page though, the crossed out style doesnt stay. the jquery style change isnt permanent. it there a way to make this change permanent?

```
$('table').on('click','.dead',function(){

          $(this).parent().siblings().css({textDecoration: 'line-through'});

    });
```

and the php

```
<?php while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<tr>

<td><?php echo $row['title']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo  $row['requester']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['reward']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['qual']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['time']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['category']; ?></td>
<td><a href="<?php $row['link']; ?>"><button class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type="button">Do This Hit</button></a></td>
<td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini dead" type="button">Dead</button></td>

</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You are applying that style during the .click event, but there is no persistence. I wouldn't say there is a "right" answer here. You'd need to either set a value in a cookie, session variable, or in the database itself, to gain some sort of persistence.

Comment: permanently is not possible.unless you have to modify your db for an extra field ,a flag yes or no for text decoration is set and then while looping use style based on that

Comment: Does the cross out indicate anything in the database?

Comment: the cross out means that certain info in the row is dead or no longer active

Comment: You have quit a bit more to do, you would have to set the record in the database as marked (probably va AJAX). Then in your while loop, you would need to build in some logic that would set the records CSS to line-through.

Answer (score 1):

Your html, .js and .css code is all pulled from the server every time the page is requested. That means whatever styles you apply via .JS will be wiped away the next time the page is requested, that is what you are seeing now.

You the developer are responsible for programming some sort of stored flag, and read it on $(document).ready() so that when the page is requested and the dom is ready the first thing it will do is check your persisted flag and it can re-apply the the current state of your style (either on or off, or in your case, line-through or no line-through)

There are many options for how you go about persisting that flag. You could set a cookie, you could use Session storage, you could use LocalStorage, or you could even set a flag in your database. It's up to you to provide the persistence of that state.

If you are supporting modern browsers you could try setting a flag in localstorage()
http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/jQuery.localStorage